# Interfacing to a Brother PTouch printer?

Tags: printing, qr-code

The Brother PTouch QL series of printers have USB interfaces and are capable of printing QR codes.  Here's a typical model:

http://www.ptouchdirect.com/ptouch/new_ql570.html

How can I prepare input (i.e. format) for these printers and talk to them directly from my program?  I'm interested in Windows, Mac, Linux platforms.  Any language, a Python library would be perfect.

I don't want to generate output (e.g. CSV) and ask the user to load that into the Brother-supplied application.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library for printing QR barcodes. It can generate the barcode image and put it in a PDF file, which the user can send to the printer. It is a Java based library and there is also a .NET port available.

Comment: How do you scale the output to the appropriate size for the printer?  Does your library have support for word wrapping given a label output width?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak about Windows, but Brother traditionally has very comprehensive Linux support.  [Here's the driver list for the PTouch models](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_esp.html).  With these drivers in place, you can print through CUPS (via the `lp` or `lpr` commands) using whatever darn file format you find is convenient for you.

OS X also uses CUPS, so printing to it would be pretty similar as on Linux... given that you can find the correct drivers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a brotherprint package, part of pypi:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/brotherprint/0.1.1

It will *supposedly* handle sending sockets, but I have not tried it:

```
import re
'''Brother Python EscP Command Library
Description:
A collection of functions to more easily facilitate printing to the Brother QL label
printers without having to memorize the ESC/P commands. Also handles sending to sockets
for you.
'''
class BrotherPrint:
font_types = {'bitmap': 0,
'outline': 1}
def __init__(self, fsocket):
self.fsocket = fsocket
self.fonttype = self.font_types['bitmap']
```

see: https://github.com/fozzle/python-brotherprint/blob/master/brotherprint/brotherprint.py